# Best way to store authenticated user in redux state

Tags: express, redux, next.js

I am currently building an app using the following

- Next.js
- Express API
- Redux-Toolkit & RTK Query

I have all of the authentication logic implemented, but have ran into an issue.

So, upon successful login, the express api returns 2 httponly cookies containing the access/refresh tokens.

I have an endpoint in my api to get the current user using the access token i.e `/api/auth/me`

This all works fine, but what I can't figure out is the best way to fetch the user on each page load and store them in the redux state.

Do I use RTK Query to hit the `/api/auth/me` endpoint and just call the query whenever I need it throughout the app?

Ideally I fetch and set the user in `_app.tsx`, but I cannot use redux dispatch since it's outside of the `<Provider store={store}></Provider>`

Also for example if I wanted to use the redux stored user in `getServerSideProps` I can't seem to do that either because it's not client side and doesn't have access to redux.

I just can't seem to find a good way to simply set the authenticated user and be able to use them globally throughout the app whether it's inside redux store or in something like `getServerSideProps`.

Any advice would be truly amazing, I am totally lost.

Comment: I'm not familiar with next.js or RTK Query, but normally you'd simply dispatch a fetchUser action when the main App component mounts, since that happens for every page load.

Answer (score 0):

One way of persisting authentication state is storing the token in the local storage.  And in the main App component you can check whether the token is present in the redux store. If it's not there you can set it manually in useEffect function.

As such:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetchAuthTokenFromLocalStorage().then((token) => {
  dispatch(setAuthenticationResult(token));
});},[dispatch]);
```